# We are tring to configure for the first time Text To Speech bt Watson in Node Red with no luck

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red

Please find attached Node-Red example, using Watson's APIs, but no luck.
We tried to connect MQlight components, Javascript functions for accessing only the API, and more.

Please find attached JSON files to import in Node-Red.

```
[{
    "id":"e40a3407.1bf5c8",
    "type":"inject",
    "name":"",
    "topic":"",
    "payload":"Watson Please talk",
    "payloadType":"string",
    "repeat":"10",
    "crontab":"",
    "once":false,
    "x":205,
    "y":176,
    "z":"8e90dcc6.716f2",
    "wires":[["df84c369.207b4"]]},
    {"id":"df84c369.207b4",
    "type":"watson-text-to-speech",
    "name":"Watson Text-To-Speech",
    "voice":"VoiceEnUsMichael",
    "x":416,
    "y":262.9999237060547,
    "z":"8e90dcc6.716f2",
    "wires":[["6174536a.9e8bac"]]},
    {"id":"6174536a.9e8bac",
    "type":"debug",
    "name":"",
    "active":true,
    "console":"false",
    "complete":"false",
    "x":631.857177734375,
    "y":172.14283752441406,
    "z":"8e90dcc6.716f2",
    "wires":[]
}]
```

Comment: In that flow you have an Inject node, the Watson node and a debug node - no sign of MQLight there. Can you describe more fully what you are trying to do and what specific problems you are encountering?

Comment: I beleive this user trying to achieve : http://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/ in Node-RED

Comment: We are trying to set up TTS by watson to work on Node red application ( we need it for use of Iot), we are injecting text and we need it to be played on our Web application that is configured in Node red also, is there some configuration example or if you can tell us what nodes are needed and how it should be configured

Comment: We tryed the example above with no luch, we need to transfer the audio WAV files from the TTS service to a web application and play it yher automaticly, if some one can give us  a simple example it will be great .

Comment: Do you see the audio files coming back from the service or an error message? The service will only give you back the raw audio buffer or a URL to the wav file. You need to manually create a way to play this on the client machine. Node-RED executes the Nodes in the server so there's no way to automatically play the audio through the browser. One way around this would be to create a HTTP end point in Node-RED that served the file. You could then hit that URL from a local browser.

Answer (score 0):

The transcribed audio will come out of the Watson speech to text node on `msg.speech`.  It will be a Buffer object.

Comment: Thanks, I had a debug node and chenge the output insted of msg.payload to msg.speech, is that what you ment or his there a special node for that ?

Comment: On top of that how can I transfer this audio files in the cash to my web application ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Stackoverflow is a community that will provide help but part of that help requires showing some of the things you have tried to get there.

Comment: I know now how to transfer the audio buffer to HTML page, can some one give me an example on how to play this audio files on the HTML5 page on the mobile ?